# Change Key type for membership provider

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I am using membership provider in my application, i am using the RolesID as a foreign key in other tables, this tables have a really huge number of rows (around 500,000 row), the performance will be better if i am able to change the keys for membership tables to be integer instead of uniqueidentifier (GUID). 
Is this possible?

Comment: You cannot change it easily; it is used in a lot of places. 500,000 is not a lot of records to slow down query when using UniqueIdentifier. Did you already compare the results or you are just guessing?

Comment: actually i am guessing as i am not able to test it, but i will check again maybe i missed something, thanks for your help